# How to make this kind of animation?

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios7, ios8

I need some kind of start point or concept advise on how to get this kind of animation, like in stock iOS calendar app.

[image]

I need infinite scrolling view, animating day numbers and date. If there is some Calendar app clone where this part presents, I would appreciate link. I have searched a lot in Github, but couldn't find particularly this part. Is it only page control on scrollable area and just labels on top? How I get the circle part to invert font? Or is it 2 sets of pictures from 1 to 31?

Comment: this [tutorial](http://www.code4app.net/ios/Weekly-calendar-view-for-iphone,-scrollable/54c5daefe24741cf0dc54249) may help. or may be few more options [here](http://www.code4app.net/category/calendar)

Comment: I have seen them, but couldn't find those parts which I am interested there.

Comment: Take a look at : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, but I think I might be able to shed at least a little bit of light. I just had a similar problem with the scroll view part. To get it to switch the date at the top, implement scrollViewDidScroll inside your scrollView class. Like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let xOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    if xOffset >= currentViewsFarRightSide 
        {
            //move date to the next date
        }
}
```

So you are checking the xOffset of the scroll view and once it has reached the next multiple of the screen width, it jumps to the next date above. Now for the inverting and stuff, there might be a better way, but having two images would also work like you suggested. You can even create a transition and inside the if statement you could do a

```
UIView.animateWithDuration
```

With your image transition and it could look pretty nice. Hope I helped in some way. Good luck!

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?